# `_pickle.UnpicklingError: the STRING opcode argument must be quoted`

Tags: python, pickle

I have a text file that I am trying to picke using python pickle.

```
tx b'88877343430010000000000'
tx b'59343410000000000'
rx b'344454320000000004'
```

I am using the following python code to serialize the file.I am getting the following error. `_pickle.UnpicklingError: the STRING opcode argument must be quoted`. I can't find anything wrong with the pickle file.

```
import six.moves.cPickle
file = open('test.txt', 'rb')        
loaded = six.moves.cPickles.load(file)
```

Comment: Are you trying to *unpickle* the text file into a Python object? If so, where did it come from? If it wasn't generated by the same version of the pickle library as you are using, that may not be possible. Create an object similar to the one that you want to load and see how it looks with  `cPickle.dumps(myObj)`

Comment: anyone got answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `cPickle.load()` you are trying to unpickle (deserialize) a previously pickled file into a Python object.

To pickle (serialize) an object to a file you should use `cPickle.dump()`.

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs if the file you are trying to load wasn't generated by the same version of the pickle library as you are using, that may not be possible. The solution to this is to open the file and save it again without editing anything and then go back and rerun your program.

Create an object similar to the one that you want to load and see how